# REACT : add loading in virtualized list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I want to when scrolling body add skeleton loading my items in virtualized list

I use the react-viewport-list package

```
 <ViewportList items={dataTable}>
              {(item, index) => (
                <Row
                  data={data}
                  index={index}
                  setSize={setSize}
                  windowWidth={windowWidth}
                />
              )}
            </ViewportList>
```